# C#: Passing argument to multiple System.Timers.Timer, when argument changes, all timers change

Tags: c#, timer

I tried to pass argument multiple System.Timers.Timer in the following code and expected the outcome to be a sequence that consists of "1" and "2". But the result turn out to be "2, 2, 2...".

```
    private static void tmer(object sender, EventArgs e, int i)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int x = 1;
        Timer tm1 = new Timer(1000);
        tm1.Elapsed += (sender, e) => tmer(sender, e, x);
        tm1.Enabled = true;

        x++;
        Timer tm2 = new Timer(1000);
        tm2.Elapsed += (sender, e) => tmer(sender, e, x);
        tm2.Enabled = true;
    }
```

Then I revised my code to the following one and I worked. Could anybody explain this to me. Many Thanks.

```
    private static void tmer(object sender, EventArgs e, int i)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i + " called.");
    }
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int x = 1;
        Timer tm1 = new Timer(1000);
        tm1.Elapsed += (sender, e) => tmer(sender, e, x);
        tm1.Enabled = true;

        Timer tm2 = new Timer(1000);
        tm2.Elapsed += (sender, e) => tmer(sender, e, 2);
        tm2.Enabled = true;
    }
```

Comment: It's got nothing to do with timers, really. Lambdas capture *variables*, not the *values* that they happen to contain at the time the lambda is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got results 2, 2 because `tmer(sender, e, x)` is executed when elapsed event is triggered and value of x in that moment is 2.

Answer (score 0):

I think that in your first code, x++ is executed before the call of your tmer function.
Therefore, tmer function is called with 2 as a value for x.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the first timer, when the Elapsed event is fired, x = 2, and this is captured.

Try copying the x into a variable that exists only within the scope of the lambda and use the copy instead.